# Can all algebraic numbers be expressed as definite integrals of rational functions with rational coefficients over rational domains?

Tags: analysis

If this is possible, how would I go about proving this? It's ok for the function to be defined in multiple variables and use multiple integrals, given that the domain itself is also defined by rational functions.

Comment: Perhaps you could say something about why you think that this might/should be the case?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_periods 
The definition of a period says that it's the integral of a algebraic function over an algebraic domain. I don't know why this would be the case, but I was just wondering if the word "algebraic" could be reduced to "rational" and have it still work.

Comment: Do you have an example of an irrational algebraic number that can be expressed in this way? My cursory attempts at finding such an expression failed; I always get either a rational number or a number that's likely transcendental.